# How to use the columns to divide the DataFrame into groups?

Tags: python, pandas

At first, DataFrame likes this:

[image: first]

I wish to change it like this:

[image: then]

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! For better view of your question, please don't put your code in photos, but better to copy & paste the text directly into the body of question so it's readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df.set_index(['Entity_Name','State_Name','State_Group','State_Type'], inplace=True)
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'State_Value':[4,5,6],
                   'State_Type':[7,1,2],
                   'State_Group':[1,3,5],
                   'State_Name':[5,3,1],
                   'Entity_Name':[7,7,7]})

df.set_index(['Entity_Name','State_Name','State_Group','State_Type'], inplace=True)
df.sort_index(inplace=True)

print (df)
                                               State_Value
Entity_Name State_Name State_Group State_Type             
7           1          5           2                     6
            3          3           1                     5
            5          1           7                     4
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a module called **itertools**.
use the **groupby** method on the specific column.

(if not helpful let me know)

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to keep the duplicates? If you don't, the `groupby` is made for you!

```
Frame.groupby(['Entity_name','State_Name','State_Group','State_Type']).first()
```